# How to go down from Grotto town when the staircase is locked in Nethack

Tags: nethack

I am playing Nethack as a lawful female human valkyrie.  I went down straight to Minetown, which was found to be of Grotto type, with my feline friend.  From reading a spoiler I know where the staircase further down into the dungeon is located.  The problem is that the door to the room it is in is locked.

In the presence of watchmen I cannot break the door or dig the wall of the room.  I could dig a hole in the floor to go down, but then I would have to leave my kitten in the town.

How can I go down from the town with my pet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

If you have the [spell of knock](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Spellbook_of_knock) or a [wand of opening](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand_of_opening), you can unlock the door without angering the Watch.

If you can obtain a key and you haven't already been warned by the Watch, then you can apply it on the door to unlock it, and you should only get a warning.

As Sconibulus pointed out, you can just wait for the Watch to be out of sight and then kick down the door as you normally would. The Watch only goes after you if they *see* you do something they don't like.

Finally, you *can* use your wand of digging or a pickaxe to go down a floor, and if you do it when your kitten is next to you, then it will just follow you down as though you had gone down the stairs with it. If your kitten is too far away to follow, you can just return by the up-stair on that floor and kick the door open from the inside. This shouldn't present a problem with the watch because none of them can see you do it, and you'll be reunited with your kitten.

Comment: Additionally, you can just wait until the watchman is out of direct line of sight, then treat the door like any other dungeon door. Further possibilities include getting your pet to kill the watchman.

Comment: When I dig a hole on the floor and fell down to the next level, my kitten followed me.  Is this what happens always?

Comment: Oh, right, I had forgotten. If you fall down a hole when your kitten is next to you, it's like going down the stairs with your kitten next to you and your kitten follows.